# Combining two private keys to create an asymmetric digital signature

Tags: authentication, cryptography, digital-signature, signature, digital

There is some algorithm which signs with a private key and verifies with a public key.
Private and public keys are created in pairs.

Assume we have 2 pairs of private and public keys.

Is there a way to combine two private keys to one private key priv_comb, so that the produced signature S, computed with this priv_comb, could be verified with either of those two public keys?

Or does this make sense at all?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the question about a generic cryptographic question and therefore should be asked on https://crypto.stackexchange.com

Comment: Continued here: https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/55693/1172